# Am using android-times-square but it will not allow me to call the method clearSelectedDates()

Tags: java, android, calendar

In CalendarPickerView I can call:

```
calendar.highlightDates(datesList);
```

But it will not allow me to call:

```
calendar.clearSelectedDates();
```

But both are clearly methods of CalendarPickerView and I am not sure why I cannot access both of them. Repo below and methods found in lines 811-837.

https://github.com/square/android-times-square/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/squareup/timessquare/CalendarPickerView.java

Using Gradle compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'

Any insight much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version. At the time of version 1.6.5, the `clearSelectedDates()` method was not yet implemented.

Try instead version 1.7.7.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: initCalendar() Method now I am not getting in version 1.7.7